# Are trigonometric functions in the span of the collection $\{x^n\}$ of monomials?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

> Do trigonometric functions belong to span of $\{x^n\}$?

I consider the answer to be yes, since all trigonometric function can be expressed in terms of powers of $x$.

Comment: Have a look at the definition of a [linear span](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_span).  Can a trigonometric function be expressed as a finite linear combination of monomials $x^n$?

Answer (score 3):

No. By definition the span of a collection $S$ of vectors is the set of all *finite* linear combinations of elements of $S$. In this case, the span of the elements $\{x^n\}$, $n \in \{0, 1, 2, \ldots\}$, (regarded as vectors, say, in $C(\Bbb R)$) consists of the finite linear combinations of the monomials $x^n$, namely, the subspace of all real polynomials over $\Bbb R$.

There is the separate issue that "trigonometric functions" is usually regarded to including functions like $x \mapsto \tan x$, which isn't even defined for all real numbers. This question could certainly benefit for some additional precision, but probably the answer remains no for any reasonable clarification.